# How to show all 4 borders in R `hist()`?

Tags: r

R `hist()` shows only the bottom and left border by default.  In `plot()`, we can use `frame.border=TRUE` to show all 4 borders.  In hist, not so.  Is there a way to show all 4 borders in `hist()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `box()` to enclose the plot figure you just created in a "box" on all four sides as you desire.

#### Code

```
> hist(mtcars$disp)
> box()
```

#### Output

[image]

#### Details

Per `help(box)`:

```
Draw a Box around a Plot

Description:

     This function draws a box around the current plot in the given
     color and linetype.  The ‘bty’ parameter determines the type of
     box drawn.  See ‘par’ for details.
```